# how to convert python ‘s byte array to QByteArray?

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I have a python ‘s byte array
b=b'hello'
and I want to use it as the parameter of QtextStream to create a QtextStream object ,but QtextStream accept Qt’s byte array rather than Python’s .I wonder is there anyway to to convert python ‘s byte array to QByteArray ?

I’ve tested the following code ,it seems I cannot do it in this way .

```
>>> b=b'hello'
>>> from PyQt4.QtCore import *
>>> c=QTextStream(QByteArray(b)).readAll()
>>> c
''
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the issue is that `QByteArray` object is constructed, passed to the `QTextStream` and then immediately destroyed. `QTextStream` doesn't make a copy of data, it only keeps a pointer to the data source. Since the source is destroyed, no data can be longer read. I even managed to get segmentation fault error when trying to call `readAll()` using some variations of your code. So, the solution is to store your `QByteArray` object in a variable as long as you need it.

> ```
> >>> buf = QByteArray(b)
> >>> c = QTextStream(buf).readAll()
> >>> c
> PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'hello')
> ```

The original question 'how to convert python ‘s byte array to QByteArray?' do not refer to your issue. It easy to see that it can be done using the obvious way:

```
>>> QByteArray(b)
PyQt4.QtCore.QByteArray('hello')
```

Comment: you said “I even managed to get segmentation fault error when trying to call readAll() using some variations of your code”
can you show me your code ?

Comment: This code crashes my Python interactive shell: `b = b'test'; c=QTextStream(QByteArray(b)); c.readAll()`

Comment: In this case it means that there was an attempt to use data of an object that has been already deleted. Exactly the same behavior can be observed if someone write C++ equivalent of this code.

Comment: PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray().append('hello') is what would only work for me in PyQT5 + Python 3.x

Comment: @Mark (and anyone else trying this with PyQt5): PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'hello') should also work here.